# Populate Samba AD reverse zone

Tags: linux, dns, samba

The problem is to populate reverse zone PTR records as found in Forward DNS zones in internal samba4 DNS implementation.

The forward zone output can be captured with the following command:

```
samba-tool dns query adserver example.com @ A
```

The output has the following format:

```
  Name=, Records=0, Children=0
  Name=host1, Records=1, Children=0
    A: 192.168.0.12 (flags=f0, serial=2, ttl=900)
  Name=host2, Records=1, Children=0
    A: 192.168.0.13 (flags=f0, serial=5, ttl=900)
```

What is needed is the script to automate creation of reverse zone records.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample script in python:

```
import socket
import re
import sys

dns_server = sys.argv[1]
zone_name = sys.argv[2]
dns_file = open(sys.argv[3],'r')
current_hostname = ""
for line in dns_file:
    match_name = re.match( r'^\s*Name=([-0-9A-Za-z]+),',line)
    if match_name:
        current_hostname=match_name.group(1)
    match_addr = re.match( r'^\s*A:\s*(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\s+',line)
    if current_hostname and match_addr:
        current_addr=\
           match_addr.group(1) + "." + \
           match_addr.group(2) + "." + \
           match_addr.group(3) + "." + \
           match_addr.group(4)
        print "samba-tool dns add " + dns_server + " " + \
             match_addr.group(3) + "." + \
             match_addr.group(2) + "." + \
             match_addr.group(1) + ".in-addr.arpa " + \
             match_addr.group(4) + " PTR " + \
             current_hostname + "." + zone_name
dns_file.close()
```

The script will output a sequence of samba-tool commands that will automate creation of reverse zone records.